# displaying images that are retrieved from json url

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have a json url like such...

[{"Image":"http://xyz.com/abc.png",
 "Title":"Sample"},{"Image":"http://xyz.com/def.png",
 "Title":"Sample2"}

]

What i want to achieve is to get the image from json url and display it into a list. Beside it there must be title. There will be number of such objects so they must be in a list form. I couldnt understand how to get started. Any suggestions with sample code will be of great help... Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse the json response you have obtained.
fetch the image url from them
these urls are just the link

establish an http connection to this url and fetch the image
the response of this connection will send  image in bytes
convert it to bitmap or encoded image
and display

remember to process server requests in form of queue if there exists many urls fro many images